# Triangle made out of 'abc' [python]

Tags: python, function, geometry

i have a problem with this code, what it is supposed to do is:

```
    a
   b c
  a b c
 a b c a
b c a b c
```

I want to create a function pyramid(n), where n is number of rows. And I want to make it out of 'abc'. I can create triangle looking like this, but without a changing letter. I was thinking of some for loop from 1 to 3, but can't come up with something where it wouldn't be doing this:

```
    a
   b b
  c c c
 a a a a
b b b b b
```

Or printing thinks multiple times (as it would be for loop (for rows) in for loop (from 1 to 3, for changing the letter)).

Those are my attempts:

```
def pyramid(n):
    word = 'abc'
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print (" "*(n-i), " ".join(word[1]*i))

    """ Just for help, to see how it works, if I can't come up with something
    while looking at it. (n-1) would be (n-i) in loop.

    print(" "*(n-1),'a')
    print(" "*(n-2),'b','c')
    print(" "*(n-3),'a','b','c')
    print(" "*(n-4),'a','b','c','a')
    print(" "*(n-5),'b','c','a','b','c')

    """

""" Corectly looking solution, but just for one number.    
def pyramid(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print (" "*(n-i), " ".join(str(n)*i))
"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
from functools import partial

def pyramid(n):
    c = cycle("abc")       #cycle returns items in cycle
    max_width = (2*n) - 1  #determine the max width(bottom row)
    f = partial("{:^{width}}".format, width=max_width)
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print (f(" ".join(islice(c, i))))
```

If you don't want to import anything then you'll have to keep a global counter that will be incremented each time you print a character and so you'll have to use `counter % 3` to access the next character from `"abc"`:

```
def pyramid(n):
    word = "abc"
    counter = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print (" "*(n-i), end="")
        for j in range(i):
            print (word[counter%len(word)], end=" ")
            counter += 1
        print()
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. However, "print f(" ".join(islice(c, i)))" throws an error invalid syntax (f is outside of that print, but if i put it inside it will print it as a string). Also I would like to as what does the "partial" and "islice" do ?

Comment: The second one is awesome ! Just one more question, is the word[counter%len(word)] similar to word[counter:len(word)] or is it something else ?

Comment: @Matis It is something else. Suppose we have printed the first three characters `"abc"` and the `counter` is at 3, now we want to print "a" again, so `3 % 3` will be 0, hence `word[0]` will be printed and this process continues.

Comment: Oh, damn it :D It is a modulo, i thought it is something more complex :D

Comment: @Matis `islice(c, i)` means return the next `i` items from `c`.

Comment: @Matis You need to use `print()` as function in Python 3, that's why the syntax error.

Comment: If I may ask you one more question. How do you do that ? how do you make print() a function so that it works. The second solution is great and working I am asking just for a further use /knowledge.

Comment: @Matis By adding parenthesis after it. `print(100)` is a function call and `print 1` is a statement. Have you tried my updated code? (Earlier it was  `print f(" ".join(islice(c, i)))` now I changed it to `print (f(" ".join(islice(c, i))))`)